# Display Return from Firebase Function

Tags: html, angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Did some more reading, some more edits, and I am at a point now where I think my main problem is when I am calling my function in `calculator.component.ts`

Again my html looks as such (edited it slightly from last time):

**app.component.html**

```
<div>
  <h1 align="center">Calculator App with Firebase</h1>
<app-calculator> </app-calculator>
```

**calculator.component.html**

```
<div>
  <label for="numField1"> Number 1:
  <input [(ngModel)]="numField1">
</label>
<br><br>
<label for="numField2"> Number 2:
  <input [(ngModel)]="numField2">
</label>
<br><br>
<button id = "calculate" (click)="getFirebaseFunction()">Calculate</button>
<br>
<br>
<p>Solution: {{sum | async | json}} </p>
</div>
```

**calculator.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator',
  templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
})
export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() firstNumber: Number
  @Input() secondNumber: Number

  constructor() {  }

  ngOnInit() {
   }

  getFirebaseFunction() {

    const numField1 = this.firstNumber;
    const numField2 = this.secondNumber;
    var sum = 0


   let addNumbers = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sum')

   addNumbers({data: (numField1, numField2)}).then(function(result) {
     this.sum = result.data.result
   })
  }  

}
```

and lastly, my firebase function
**index.ts**

```
export const sum = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
    const numField1 = data.Number
    const numField2 = data.Number




    if (!Number.isFinite(numField1) || !Number.isFinite(numField2)) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'Both Number Fields are Required for Addition')
    }
    return {
        firstNumber: numField1,
        secondNumber: numField2,
        operator: '+',
        result: numField1 + numField2
    }
})
```

When I run this, I am faced with the following error:

`Error: Both Number Fields are Required for Addition` which I'm taking to mean based on my function that it is not recognizing that the inputs numField1 and numField2 aren't being passed into the function and I think it is because I have something wrong in `addNumbers({data: (numField1.valueOf, numField2.valueOf)}).then(function(result) {
     this.sum = result.data.result
   })` <-- this statement, not sure what else I should be putting in there the documentation provided by firebase only deals with one constant called `text`.

Comment: You should put some logging statements at every stage of both the client and server to make sure you're sending and receiving exactly what you expect. I think you might be surprised at what's actually going on. In other words, learn how to debug code by examining the values of things that are being used at each stage of processing.

Comment: I'm guessing the situation is a little more dire than I expected then, I am relatively new to this type of stuff mostly self-teaching here, so basically inject some `console.log(x)` statements along the way to see what's going on?

Comment: Many things in programming are different than what the code author expects.  That's why there are millions of questions on Stack Overflow.  Things are not "dire", they just need understanding.  That's what debugging is for.

Comment: I guess dire was poor word choice there but I understand what you're saying in general

Comment: first off @DougStevenson I would like to thank you for the push in the right direction below I am going to post an answer which I'm hoping is a valid answer but I appreciate the tip as I have gotten at least the basic answer to my question through some trial/error and debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there were a couple of things wrong with what I was approaching above below is the correct way to achieve what I am trying to achieve and I will try and explain as best as I can below, in case someone stumbles upon similar issues in the future.

**modified calculator.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireFunctions } from '@angular/fire/functions';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-calculator',
  templateUrl: './calculator.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./calculator.component.css']
})
export class CalculatorComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() firstNumber: Number
  @Input() secondNumber: Number
  sum = 0

  constructor() {  }

  ngOnInit() {
   }

  getFirebaseFunction() {
    const addNumbers = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('sum');
    const numField1 = Number(this.firstNumber);
    const numField2 = Number(this.secondNumber); 

    addNumbers({
      firstNumber : numField1,
      secondNumber: numField2
    }).then((result) => {
      this.sum = result.data.result
    }
  )}
}
```

**modified index.ts**

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';

// // Start writing Firebase Functions
// // https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/typescript
//
export const sum = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
    const firstNumber = data.firstNumber
    const secondNumber = data.secondNumber




    if (!Number.isFinite(firstNumber) || !Number.isFinite(secondNumber)) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError('invalid-argument', 'Both Number Fields are Required for Addition')
    }
    return {
        firstNumber: firstNumber,
        secondNumber: secondNumber,
        operator: '+',
        result: Number(firstNumber) + Number(secondNumber)
    }
})
```

The main point of understanding for this was:

- In the suspected problematic line I basically needed to equate the inputs for the fields with their associated properties in the function so that when the calculate button was clicked, the program would understand that we are passing `numField1` for `firstNumber` and `numField2` for `secondNumber`